# Object array with variable from another class

Tags: java, arrays, class

Worksheet Question:

*The question said to declare an array of 5 objects of the class Node in the main Class* - I managed to this as shown below

*But then the question continues populate the array by objects with seqNo values assigned to 1,2,3,4,5 respectively. Then traverse the array and print the list of its object using method show()*

I have an error when I am trying to show the array to the user.
I am trying to display the array by this line of code:

```
nodObj[].show();
```

Below I have all the code except the Person class. Does someone have any idea if I should do a loop. When i tried if loop I got an error too. I have the display part code wrong I can't figure out what to change

My AnyClass

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AnyClass
{
public int seqNo;

/* -----------------Constructor------------*/
public  AnyClass(int num) 
{
     seqNo = num; //initializing 
}
//empty constructor
public  AnyClass() 
{
     
}
//intialized    
public void initializeseqNo(int seqNum)
{
    seqNum = seqNo;
}
/*-----Mehtods*/
public String getData()
{return "Sequence number " +seqNo+".";
}

public String getKey()
{
    return String.valueOf(seqNo); //for search by seqNo
}

public void editData() //empty method to be overriden by future subcclasses
{
    
}

public void edit(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    seqNo = sc.nextInt();//next line for String
}

} //end of AnyClass
```

My Node class

```
public class Node
{
public AnyClass obj;

public Node(AnyClass newObj)
{ 
    obj = newObj;
}

public void show()
{
    System.out.println(obj.getData());
}
}
```

MainProg

```
class MainProg{
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        //-----------Construction of objects---------
        Person head = new Person ("Gatt", 21445667);
        Person clerk = new Person();
        clerk.name = "Delia";

        System.out.println ("Data of a new Head: " +head.getData());

        AnyClass ac1 = new AnyClass(51);
        AnyClass ac2 = new AnyClass(52);
        AnyClass ac3 = new AnyClass(53);

        ac1.getData();
        ac2.getData();
        ac3.getData();
        
        
        //edit value of ac1
        ac1.edit();
        
        //print all values again
        ac1.getData();
        ac2.getData();
        ac3.getData();

        Node n = new Node(new AnyClass(3));

        //print values
        n.show();

        Node nodObj[] = new Node[5]; //allocating memory to array
        
        //populate array
        nodObj[0] = new Node(new AnyClass(1));
        nodObj[1] = new Node(new AnyClass(2));
        nodObj[2] = new Node(new AnyClass(3));
        nodObj[3] = new Node(new AnyClass(4));
        nodObj[4] = new Node(new AnyClass(5));

        //printing array
        
        nodObj[].show(); //ERROR THIS IS WRONG!

        
    }//end of Main()
}//end of program class
```

Comment: `Node` is not an array, so you can't assign it to an array.  You have to assign it to an *element* of the array.  `nodObj[0] = new Node(n.AnyClass);`  Note the "0".  This is basic syntax that should have be covered in your class.

Comment: thank you already helpful to me and with online classes I have an elderly who can barely speak loudly so whole class struggling to hear lectures about the Node concept

Comment: If you're really struggling in class, you should talk to your instructor.  At least they should be able to write code on a board so everyone can see it, even if you can't hear them well.  Also your text book should have examples.  But seriously, talk to your instructor, if the whole class is struggling the instructor needs to know.

Comment: thank you again and yes we informed him but he didnt try we will see in next lecture if he fixes problem if not we take more action

Comment: Please show the code for Node and AnyClass. From your description, I'm struggling to even understand the beginning problem.

Comment: I expect the idea is that you have five statements that look like `nodeObj[0] = new Node(new AnyClass(1));` (with the 0 and 1 changed each time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Below I have all the code except the Person class. Does someone have
> any idea if I should do a loop. When i tried if loop I got an error
> too. I have the display part code wrong I can't figure out what to
> change

Yes, you need to loop over the array. At this level of instruction you should use a for or foreach loop.

```
for (int index = 0; index < nodObj.length; index++) {
  nodObj[index].show();
}
```

Or

```
for (Node node : nodObj) {
  node.show();
}
```

Comment: Simple for loops are more performant than foreach (the second type), but less readable. Where you don't need maximum performance, you should use the foreach loop.